# REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED: sftp -v -o HostKeyAlgorithms=... : Cannot use "ecdsa" and "rsa" in parallel

Tags: ssh, openssh, sftp

When I connect to my "OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.4" server alternating using "`sftp -v -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 test-user@localhost`" and "`sftp -v -o HostKeyAlgorithms=rsa-sha2-256 test-user@localhost`" I always get when switching from one algorithm to the other the following warning:

> "WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!". Is this the
> correct behavior that it is not possible to use ECDSA and RSA
> Host-Key-Algorithms in parallel or is this a bug?

Comment: Is there any reason to switch the host encryption algorithm?

Comment: Hi Romeo - no there is no reason besides that I'm actually testing my Android SFTP Server s0 v1 (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.becke.sftp_server__s0_v1) and according to the specifications: “SSH File Transfer Protocol Version 3”, “The Secure Shell (SSH) Protocol Architecture (RFC4251)”, “The Secure Shell (SSH) Transport Layer Protocol (RFC4253)”, “The Secure Shell (SSH) Authentication Protocol (RFC4252)” and “The Secure Shell (SSH) Connection Protocol (RFC4254)” there is no reason why ecdsa and rsa can't be used in parallel.